# prove set definition - by induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

$X\subseteq Z^+$ defined recursively as:

$1)$ $3\in X$; and

$2)$ If $a,b\in X$, then $a+b\in X$.

Prove that $X=\{3k|k\in Z^+\},$ the set of all positive integers divisible by $3$.

Induction on the size of set $X$.  If $X$ has one element it must be $3$ by $i)$.  This forms the base case.  Assume true for $|X_n|=n$. $X_n=\{3,3i_1,3i_2,...,3i_{n-1}\}$.  By $ii)$ $X_{n+1}=\{3,3i_1,3i_2,...,3i_{n-1},3i_j+3i_k=3(i_j+i_k)\}$.  By Principle of Mathematical Induction $X=\{3k|k\in Z^+\},$ the set of all positive integers divisible by $3$.

Comment: i think this might look better as 2 trivial inductions.  will update later.

Comment: Why was it downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

$\{3k\mid 0< k \in \mathbb{N}\} \subseteq X$ is clear,  further $\{3k\mid 0< k \in \mathbb{N}\} $ satisfies the induction assumptions so equality holds. When sets are defined recursively in this way it always means the smallest such set.

Comment: so is my attempt actually correct?  i really wasn't sure.  thanks.

Comment: i don't quite follow that it always means the smallest set.  you mean without duplicates?

Comment: @underdog: Rene means that there’s a third clause, often left unstated, in the definition of $X$: a positive integer belongs to $X$ **only** if is required to do so by the first two clauses.

Comment: @underdog $X$ can be seen as the smallest set (of integers) satisfying the set equation $X = \{3\} \cup \{a + b | a,b\in X\}$. Inductive definitions can always be formalized like this.